# My SQL query within a query

Tags: sql, mysql

I have 2 tables that I am trying to combine in a specific way
Table 1: ‘part_defs’ Table 2 Items_part_values

### in value_defs:

```
ID  | Name
-------------
  1 | color
  2 | size
  3 | weight
```

### in Items_part_values

```
ItemID | valueID | Value
-------------------------
    10 | 1       | red
    11 | 1       | blue
```

What I need is a query where for a given item all the rows from value_defs appear and if they have a value in Items_part_values the value.

So for Item 11 I want

```
ID | Name   | Value
--------------------
 1 | color  | red
 2 | size   | NULL
 3 | weight | NULL
```

I’m new to MySQL, in access I would have created a subquery with the ItemID as a parameter and then done a Left Join with value_defs on the result.

Is there a way of doing something similar in MySQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
   SELECT p.id,
          p.name,
          ipv.value
     FROM PART_DEFS p
LEFT JOIN ITEMS_PART_VALUES ipv ON ipv.valueid = p.id
                               AND ipv.itemid = ?
```

Replace the "?" with the itemid you want to search for.
This means all the `PARTS_DEF` rows will be returned, and if the `ITEMS_PART_VALUES.valueid` matches the `PART_DEFS.id` value, then the `ITEMS_PART_VALUES.value` value will be displayed for the item you are looking for.  If there's no match, the value column will be NULL for that record.

There's a difference in OUTER JOINs, when specifying criteria in the JOIN vs the WHERE clause.  In the JOIN, the criteria is applied *before* the JOIN occurs while in the `WHERE` clause the criteria is applied *after* the JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [left join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 USING (ID);
```

Edit:

```
SELECT * FROM part_defs LEFT JOIN Items_part_values ON part_defs.ID = Items_part_values.valueID;
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea and maybe I wasn’t clear but I only want the details for a single item. The left join would result in getting the details for all items

Comment: @jimmy not if you use a WHERE clause